# wlan0 RX/TX packets increase but no connection established

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ifconfig

I am wondering why the wlan0 interface on my Raspberry Pi configured as a HotSpot and not connected to any client has its "RX/TX packets" counters from ifconfig increase continuously? Since no client is connected and I'm not trying to connect to it, where does these packets come from? Thanks for your help.

Note: This might look like a beginner question. I've searched on google and on stackExchange but found nothing about it. If that information exists sorry please point it out, I'd be very grateful.

Vince

Comment: What do you mean by *continuously*? A few tens of packets per second, or a few thousands (or more) packets per second?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I mean a few tens of packets per second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you mean by continuously? A few tens of packets per second, or a few thousands (or more) packets per second?
>
> I mean a few tens of packets per second

You can check the packets passing thru your wifi interface with *tcpdump*. I just setup a hostapd server on my pc, then listened for packets:

```
 # tcpdump -i wlan0 -n
tcpdump: WARNING: wlan0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:59:16.827480 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:17.827496 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:18.827509 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:19.827489 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:20.827561 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:21.039378 IP6 fe80::6257:18ff:fe58:3db.5353 > ff02::fb.5353: 0 [3q] PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _plasma._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. (59)
17:59:21.827492 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:22.827523 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:23.827530 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:24.827605 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:25.827578 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:26.827563 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:27.827576 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:28.827617 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:29.827627 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:30.827605 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:31.827624 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:32.827678 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
17:59:33.827682 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 9000.00:0e:58:52:a5:4e.8001, length 45
```

This is the output of a couple of seconds: you see the all-important STP packets reaching the wireless interface: [the Spanning Tree Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol)

> is a Layer 2 protocol that runs on bridges and switches. The specification for STP is IEEE 802.1D. The main purpose of STP is to ensure that you do not create loops when you have redundant paths in your network. Loops are deadly to a network.

Apart from STP, I have also found [NetBios over TCP/IP packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP),

```
18:07:43.505288 IP 192.168.73.94.137 > 192.168.73.255.137: NBT UDP PACKET(137): QUERY; REQUEST; BROADCAST
```

which, being BROADCAST packets, are received by all interfaces, and

```
18:10:28.970239 IP 0.0.0.0 > 224.0.0.1: igmp query v2
```

[IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) packets. There are even more protocols, like ARP,  which reach  an AP, but, since wlan0 has no IP address, they will not be detected by *tcpdump* unless the monitor-mode option *-l* is used.

These protocols easily account for a few tens of packets per second. You can easily explore the use of these protocols by reading up on them on their Wikipedia pages.